# Apache Virtual Host redirect from subdomain to subdirectory

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

How do I redirect requests coming to `http://blog.mysite.com` to `http://mysite.com/blog`?

Reading the apache docs on [when not to use the rewrite mod](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/avoid.html), I tried a simple redirect e.g.

```
Redirect http://blog.mysite.com http://mysite.com/blog
```

But when I visit http://blog.mysite.com, it doesn't redirect me. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you do a different `<VirtualHost>` for `blog.mysite.com`?

If you can, just put your `Redirect` config there:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName blog.mysite.com
    Redirect / http://mysite.com/blog/
</VirtualHost>
```

If for some reason you still need to piggy-back on the other vhost, or need to handle all subdomains and not just "blog", then use `mod_rewrite`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.mysite\.com$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://mysite.com/%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This worked, but I had to comment out `ServerAlias *.mysite.com` in my `mysite.com` VirtualHost. That wasn't so bad. The only things it was catching were `blog.` and `www.`, so I just changed the `*` to `www` and was all set! Much thanks!