# How to automatically redirect subdomain.domain to domain/subdomain

Tags: subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Apache Virtual Host redirect from subdomain to subdirectory](https://serverfault.com/questions/419480/apache-virtual-host-redirect-from-subdomain-to-subdirectory)

Without access to cpanel, apache conf files and only access to .htacess and FTP, how can I create a hosting site that when the user tries to access for example sub.domain.com it redirects to domain.com/sub automatically. the reason is to eliminate having to create subdomains by hand. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [htaccess-rewrite-to-subfolders-for-subdomains-and-the-main-domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084235/htaccess-rewrite-to-subfolders-for-subdomains-and-the-main-domain.). Should be able to work in your `.htaccess` file.